# $f(x)=\frac{9}{2x-3}$ as a series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

The issue here (I think) is just the $c$ part:

I have to represent
$$f(x)=\frac{9}{2x-3}$$ as a series at center $c=6$, I don't want to see any Taylor Series or Maclaurin Series (we'll be working with that this week).

I started by trying to represent it as $\frac{a}{1-r}$ which equals the series
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}ar^n$$
so here goes:
$$f(x)=\frac{9}{2x-3}$$
$$=\frac{9}{-3-(-2x)}$$
$$=\frac{-3}{1-(\frac{2}{3}x)}$$
$$=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-3)\biggl(\frac{2}{3}x\biggr)^n$$
But I'm confused on how to deal with the $c=6$ part, I tried
$$=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-3)\biggl(\frac{2}{3}(x-6)\biggr)^n$$ but it was wrong according to my homework, how do I deal with center at $c=6$?

Comment: Try rewriting the denominator as $2x - 3 = 2(x - 6) + 9 = 9(1 - (-\dfrac{2}{9})(x - 6))$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** $\dfrac{9}{2x-3} = \dfrac{9}{2(x-6)+9} = \dfrac{1}{\frac{2}{9}(x-6)+1}$

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
$$f(x) = \frac{9}{2x-3} = \frac{9}{2(x - 6) + 9}.$$
Can you continue? Take $z = x - 6$ if required.